# pdf generationusing Java: Making fields bold

Tags: java, pdf

I am writing java source code to geenerate a pdf file using iText. Below code is working and generating pdf file.

```
Document document = new Document();
Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();
Font documentFont = new Font (Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, Font.NORMAL);

  preface.add(new Paragraph("Shri/Smti " + getApplicantName() + ", Roll No. " + getCandidateAckNo() + "" +
                    " is hereby allowed to appear in the examination for TESTEXAM" +
                    " to be held at " + getNameOfCenterDetails() + " as per scheduled below :", documentFont));
```

Now I want to make the `applicaneName`, `ackNo`, `centerDetails` etc in bold. I cannot make a separate line for name. I googled a lot to find some solution, but not able to find any working solution. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to compose your paragraph using [Chunks](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/) with different fonts.

Comment: yes, but if i write `preface.add(new Paragraph("" + getApplicantname(), new Font);` it will add a new line. I need in the same line.

Comment: Exactly the reason why you should be adding `new Chunk()` instead of `new Paragraph()`